# Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: proguard - release (app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease)

Tags: java, android

I tried all the options that exist in Google but nothing helped.
on gradle 1.3 version of the project was going to but when all the ones on during assembly 2,2,3 release version error.

Error when proguard enable:

```
    Error:java.lang.NullPointerException
Warning:The interface com/github/tibolte/agendacalendarview/agenda/IAgendaHeaderView has a static method "inflate" but backporting default methods is not enabled
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
Error:java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Gradle:

```
   android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    signingConfigs {
        releaseConfig {
            storeFile file("test.jks")
            storePassword "test"
            keyAlias "test"
            keyPassword "test"
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "by.test.by"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        // versionCode 1
        versionName project.props.version

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dexOptions {
//        incremental false
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048m"
        preDexLibraries = false
```

Proguard rules:

```
 -dontwarn by.mrsoft.mrdoc.**
-dontwarn com.radaee.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-adaptresourcefilenames
-adaptresourcefilecontents
-keepdirectories
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.graphics.drawable.** { *; }


-assumenosideeffects class * {
 @by.mrsoft.mrdoc.model.System.OnlyDebug *;
}

-keep class org.kxml2.** { *; }
-keep class org.acra.** { *; }
# исключение Radaee
-keep class com.radaee.** { *; }

#-keep class by.mrsoft.mrdoc.** { *; }

-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}

-keep class com.feitian.** { *; }
-keep class org.pkcs11.** { *; }
-keep class ru.aladdin.** { *; }
-keep class by.mrsoft.mrdoc.Eds.** { *; }

#-keep class java.awt.** { *; }
#-keep class javax.naming.** { *; }
#-keep class org.spongycastle.** { *; }
#-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn javax.naming.**
-keep class com.sun.** { *; }
-keep class ru.rutoken.** { *; }

-keep class ru.CryptoPro.** { *; }
-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class com.intellij.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-dontwarn ru.CryptoPro.**
-optimizationpasses 1
#-optimizations !code/allocation/variable,

-dontwarn org.apache.**
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}


-keep class android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.design.**
```

Error in gradle:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:196)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:178)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:174)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:283)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:63)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:173)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:49)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:223)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at proguard.util.FixedStringMatcher.matches(FixedStringMatcher.java:52)
    at proguard.util.OrMatcher.matches(OrMatcher.java:46)
    at proguard.classfile.util.WarningPrinter.accepts(WarningPrinter.java:89)
    at proguard.classfile.util.WarningPrinter.print(WarningPrinter.java:77)
    at proguard.AssumeNoSideEffectsChecker.checkClassSpecifications(AssumeNoSideEffectsChecker.java:86)
    at proguard.ConfigurationChecker.check(ConfigurationChecker.java:141)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:73)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:54)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:254)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling 'Instant Run' if enabled and rebuild the project. Also, see if everything is set as per the instructions given here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html

Comment: not help, error
`Error:java.lang.NullPointerException
Error:java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
Warning:The interface com/github/tibolte/agendacalendarview/agenda/IAgendaHeaderView has a static method "inflate" but backporting default methods is not enabled`

Comment: Compiling with Java 8 might be causing the issues, since its neither fully supported nor backward compatible. Try going through this and see if everything is set properly.https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html

Comment: @ Suhayl SH
your answer as the Council has not helped